# Extension method does not accept omitting first argument

Tags: c#

I am using an extension method to add elements to a list:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ByteBank.SistemaAgencia
{
    public static class ListExtensoes
    {
        public static void AdicionarVarios(this List<int> listaDeInteiros, params int[] itens)
        {
            foreach (int item in itens)
            {
                listaDeInteiros.Add(item);


            }
        }


    }
}
```

I call the method omitting the first argument:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ByteBank.Modelos;
using ByteBank.Modelos.Funcionarios;

namespace ByteBank.SistemaAgencia
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> idades = new List<int>();

            idades.Add(5);
            idades.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 99 });

            ListExtensoes.AdicionarVarios(1, 5687, 18, 255);

            for (int i = 0; i < idades.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Item: {i} Valor: {idades[i]} \n");

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

However, the compiler points to the following error:

`CS1503 - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>`'

Why can't I call the extension method without passing the first parameter?

Comment: Extension method is called like `idades.AdicionarVarios(1, 5687, 18, 255)` If calling the method explicitly from the static class, then you have to include the first argument. That is by design, as demonstrated by the compilation error

Comment: Costa.Gustavo, Can you please clarify why you expect that it's ok to not specify required parameters to a method and what kind of behavior you suggest when required parameter is missing? (I don't think question is clear in a sense of giving enough information to figure out what you don't understand/misunderstanding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Extension methods are defined as static methods but are called by using instance method syntax.

The subject extension method is called like

```
//...

idades.AdicionarVarios(1, 5687, 18, 255);

//...
```

If calling the method explicitly from the static class, then you have to include the first argument. That is by design, as demonstrated by the compilation error

> In your code you invoke the extension methods with instance method syntax. However, the intermediate language (IL) generated by the compiler translates your code into a call on the static method.

Reference [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a List of int not a single int

```
List<int> myintlist = new List<int>()
ListExtensoes.AdicionarVarios(myintlist, itens);
```

Comment: This would fix the error but defeats the purpose of an extension method.

Comment: Very true statement